# Clickable content section in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, hyperlink

I have written something here

```
## Contents 
   * [Question 1]
   * [Question 2]
   * [Question 3]
   * [Question 4]
```

I wanna sections Question 1 to be clickable. If I click it, I can directly go to the section about question 1.

Anyone have some ideas of how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add links e.g.

if you have sections named with heading in markdown cell as

```markdown
# Question 1
```

then you can use

```markdown
## Contents 
   * [Question 1](#Question-1)
```

You can also click on the symbol next to your heading to get link

[image]

Comment: I have tried before and it did not work. is it because I type Question1 not Question-1

Comment: yes, you try by clicking on symbol next to your heading, then get the correct name

Comment: thank you so much @kHarshit; But I cannot click the symbol, what is the problem? Additionally, though it works but when I click the section below content, it still cannot direct me to the section page

Comment: can you try in another browser maybe? Also, how did you write the header in markdown cell? e.g. `# Question1`?

Comment: Thank your for your reply. I wrote ```###Question 1```

Comment: hey @MathildaFang , one small problem in the way you're writing, there should be a space b/w # and text